# How to limit a users integer input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the user to input an integer from 1000 to 25000 but I don't want the user to input an integer that passes the 25000 and at the same time want the user to try it again without having to restart the program.

```
while True:
    try:
        loan_amount= int(input("How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000)"))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue
    else:
        break
if loan_amount > 25000:
    print("Sorry, We only lend up to $25,000. Please try again!")
```

I expect that when a user inputs an integer that is greater than 25,000 they will be told that "we can't lend that much try again" and then repeats the question again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to include the if else statements inside the `try` block with a `break` statement to exit the while loop if a correct amount is entered.

```
while True:
    try:
        loan_amount= int(input("How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000) "))
        if loan_amount > 25000:
            print("Sorry, We only lend up to $25,000. Please try again!")
        else:
            print ("Amount loaned")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again")
```

**Output**

*Try 1*

```
How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000) 24999
Amount loaned
```

*Try 2*

```
How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000) Donald Trump
Sorry, I didn't understand that. Please try again
How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000) 23000
Amount loaned
```

*Try 3*

```
How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000) 27000
Sorry, We only lend up to $25,000. Please try again!
How much do you want to borrow?(1000-25000) 23000
Amount loaned
```